# sql state 42830 : FK referring to a single PK in a Table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Table_1";
CREATE TABLE "Table_1" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "other_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "col3" varchar(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  "col4" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  "col5" int4,
  "col6" int4
  );


  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Table_2";
CREATE TABLE "Table_2" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "id_table_2" int4 NOT NULL,
  "col3" varchar(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  "col4" int4
  );


  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Table_3";
CREATE TABLE "Table_3" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "id_table_3" int4 NOT NULL,
  "id_item" int4 NOT NULL,
  "col4" int4,
  "col5" int4);



CREATE INDEX "first_fkey" ON "Table_1" USING btree (
  "other_id" pg_catalog."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

ALTER TABLE "Table_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id", "other_id");


CREATE INDEX "second_fkey" ON "Table_2" USING btree (
  "id_table_2" pg_catalog."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

CREATE INDEX "third_1_fkey" ON "Table_3" USING btree (
  "id_table_3" pg_catalog."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST,
  "id_item" pg_catalog."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

CREATE INDEX "third_2_fkey" ON "Table_3" USING btree (
  "id_table_3" pg_catalog."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

ALTER TABLE "Table_3" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_3_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id", "id_table_3");

ALTER TABLE "Table_2" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

ALTER TABLE "Table_3" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_3_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("id_item", "id_table_3") REFERENCES "Table_1" ("id", "other_id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE "Table_2" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("id_table_2") REFERENCES "Table_1" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Basically this is the SQL I made to create Table_1, Table_2 and Table_3, with primary keys, and Foreign in Table_2,Table_3 referring to Table_1's main id or couple Primary key, problem is I keep getting this error :

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Table_1"
>   SQL state: 42830

So far I've did everything by the book, the error suggests that I dont have a unique constraint, while I did create Primary key as soon as I created the table, so I'm totally lost right now.

using PostgreSql 12.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

You have a *composite* primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE "Table_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id", "other_id");
```

This is silly.  You know that `id` is unique, because it is `serial`.  So, just keep it as the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE "Table_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "Table_1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");
```

More suggestions:

- Do not use double quotes around identifiers.  They just make queries harder to read and write.
- Postgres now recommends `id int generated always as identity` instead of `serial`.
- I recommend doing inline primary key definitions:  `id int generated always as identity primary key`.
- If you want an index on the other column, then add that as a separate index.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'm sorry I didnt realize it would be this issue, I've updated my post as I was using another table that needed that composite primary key as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was That the composite primary key doesnt affect unique constraint on each column, So it had to be done manually for each column like this :

```
CONSTRAINT id_tb3 UNIQUE ("id")
```

inside the concerned table. and it stopped showing up the issue.